# how to fetch 1 row only without using loop for php oracle

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, ' SELECT def_usr,status,subject,type,site,def_date,VER_DATE,VER_USR,closed_date,problem,hd_no,solution,attachment FROM hdr_web where hd_no=:num2');
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":num2",$no);                 
oci_execute($stid);
$count = 0;

while (($row = oci_fetch_row($stid)) != false)
{
   $def_usr=$row[0];
   $status=$row[1];
   $subject=$row[2];
   $type=$row[3];
   $site=$row[4];
   $def_date=$row[5];
   $ver_date=$row[6];
   $VER_USR=$row[7];
   $closed_date=$row[8];
   $problem=$row[9];
   $hd_no=$row[10];
   $solution=$row[11];
   $file=$row[12];
}
```

this query just return 1 single row of data only....i think it not good use the loop for display data maybe there is other way?

Comment: Simple, don't use loop, just do `$row = oci_fetch_row($stid);`.

Comment: you might also want to check out `oci_fetch_all`, apparently you can also obtain it with something like `oci_fetch_all($stid, $result);` `$result` being what youre looking for. http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php

Comment: so the row still need arry what i means is do i need put like this $def_usr=$row[0],$status=$row[1]